# Extracting characters with certain pattern in R

Tags: r, pattern-recognition

I need to extract the characters following certain pattern. For example, I have such text:

> AASKI Technology Inc., Tinton Falls, New Jersey, HC1047-18-D-2001;
>   Accenture Federal Services...(HC1047-18-D-2002);...

I need to extract the all term: HC1047-18-D-2001. The pattern is always 5 alphanumeric dash two numeric dash one letter dash four numeric. The term is sometimes in the parenthesis sometimes not; sometimes in the middle of text sometimes at the end.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a job for regex, not statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not belong to that forum. Nevertheless, since the pattern is relatively simple and the weather is nice, you can do it maybe using the following pattern:

```
x <- c("AASKI Technology Inc., Tinton Falls, New Jersey, HC1047-18-D-200", # last digit misses
       "AASKI Technology Inc., Tinton Falls, New Jersey, HC1047--18-D-2001", # too many -
       "Accenture Federal Services...(HC1047-18-D-2002)", # ok
       "AASKI Technology Inc., Tinton Falls, New Jersey, HC1047-18-D-2001--", # ok
       "AASKI Technology Inc., Tinton Falls, New Jersey, HC1047-18-D-2001") # ok
pattern <- "[A-z0-9]{6}-{1}[0-9]{2}-{1}[A-z]{1}-{1}[0-9]{4}"

m <- regexpr(pattern, x) #  -1 -1 31 50 50
regmatches(x, m) # "HC1047-18-D-2002" "HC1047-18-D-2001" "HC1047-18-D-2001"
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. It works perfect, except only when the term is multi-line. In that case it returns empty.

Comment: Try to remove newline first `x <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", x)`

Comment: Thank you. I am working on it but in some texts it doesn't recognize this pattern even if the term is not multi-line. If you like I can post the text here. Anyway, many thanks for your help.